# How to start a program with buttons disabled - Java?

Tags: java, button

How do I start a program (that has four buttons) with three buttons disabled and one enabled. Also, when the button that is enabled is pressed I want it to become disabled and the other three to become enabled. Disregard the add and remove methods
but this is what I have so far, what should I add and/or change?

```
private void initButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
initButton.setEnabled(false);
}

private void displayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{

}

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
cdcollection.add(cdtitleInput.getText());
}

private void removeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
cdcollection.remove(cdcollection.size()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something? Can't you just call `setEnabled()` on the buttons as you create them?

To change the status in the listeners, again, just call `setEnabled()` on the relevant buttons.

Perhaps you should look into radio buttons - sounds like that is what you are trying to imitate...

Answer (score 1):

YOu can write the logic you are looking for using the `setEnabled()` method: if you pass it `false` it disables the button you called the method on, `true` enables it.  So you can set the three disabled.  Then you can register a button click listener on the button and add the opposite logic to that handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) on the JButtons.

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setEnabled(true);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast written basic examle of do this:

```
   private void initComponents() {

        controls = new Container();
        controls = getContentPane();
        controls.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        one = new JButton("Enable buttons");

        two = new JButton("Second");
        two.setEnabled(false);

        three = new JButton("Third");
        three.setEnabled(false);

        four = new JButton("Fourth");
        four.setEnabled(false);

        one.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    one.setEnabled(false);

                    if (!one.isEnabled()) {
                        two.setEnabled(true);
                        three.setEnabled(true);
                        four.setEnabled(true);
                    } 
                }
        });

        controls.add(one);
        controls.add(two);
        controls.add(three);
        controls.add(four);
    }
```